# Pandas dtypes lost when storing with parquet

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm to write a parquet file of my dataframe for later use. Type information on the dataframe columns is important for my final use case, but it seems that this information is lost when writing to and reading from a parquet file:

```
def test_parquet_dtype(self):
    pq_file_loc = 'pq.pq'
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [1,2,3,4]})
    df = df.astype({'A': 'category', 'B': 'object'})
    self.assertEqual(['category', 'object'], list(df.dtypes))

    df.to_parquet(pq_file_loc)
    new_df = pd.read_parquet(pq_file_loc)
    self.assertEqual(['category', 'object'], [str(dtype) for dtype in new_df.dtypes])

    # Expected: ['category', 'object']
    # Actual: ['int64', 'int64']
```

Is there a better way to save and retrieve a parquet file in order to maintain type information?